# if command with two different variables

Tags: python

I have a user input and then an "if statement", but in this if statement I want to check two different variables? its not working no matter what I try.

```
if hm == 3 and karma == 8:
    print ("hello whatever")
```

That's what I have tried already but it's wrong, so what do I use to check for two different variables, thanks?

edit: so i'm just experimenting making a mini-game ... this is my code so far

what happens is when it gets to the problem area it just skips to the end message

```
import time
x = 1
karma = 0
money = 50
ticket1 = 1





name = input("what is your name")
print ("hello", name)

time.sleep(1.5)

check = input("would you like to start your adventure")

if check == "yes" or "Yes" or "yeah":
    print ("good then lets get going")

else:
    print ("bye loser")
    SystemExit

time.sleep(1.5)


print ("you are walking down a road on the way to the shops, when all of a sudden a homeless man asks you for some change")
time.sleep(1)
hm = input("do you 1. give the man all your money, 2. give him some small change, 3. tell him to eff off")

if hm == "1":
    print("you gave the man all your money, karma + 10, you have no money now")
    money = 0
    karma = 10
    x = 1

if hm == "2":
    print ("you give him $10, karma + 2, you have $40 left")
    money = 40
    karma = 2
    x = 1

if hm == "3":
    print (" you tell the man to fuck off, he looks hungry and disappointed, turns out he died later that day. karma - 5, you have $50 left")
    money = 50
    karma = -5
    x = 2

print(".")
print(".")
print(".")
print(".")



time.sleep(1.5)

print ("a bit further down the road you pass a street salesman selling golden tickets,")
time.sleep(1.5)
print("he say's .. they will be worth it later on in the game , honestly..")
time.sleep(1.5)
check1 = input("do you 1. buy a ticket ($5) 2. don't buy a ticket 3. threaten to punch him unless he gives you a ticket")
time.sleep(1)

if hm == 3 and karma == -5:
    money + 5
    print("you beat the shit out of him and take a golden ticket as well as $5, karma -5, you have", money, "dollars left")
    karma = -10
    ticket1 + 1

if hm== 3:
    print ("he cowers under your influence and gives you a ticket you have ", money, "dollars left, karma - 5")
    karma -5
    ticket1 + 1

if hm == 2:
    print ("you walk on withought buying a ticket, no change in karma, you have ", money, " dollars left")

if hm == 1:
    money -10
    ticket1 +1
    print("you buy a golden ticket, you have ", money, " left")

print("well thats all folks")
```

Comment: You're missing a `:` at the end of the `if` line...

Comment: Seems right to me, except you're missing a ':' at the end of the if statement.  What exactly isn't working?

Comment: What are the values of `hm` and `karma`? Where do they come from? Hint: a `:` is necessaray at the end of the `if` line.

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error? If so, what?

Comment: When you try to run code and it fails, all the lines the python prints out are called a *traceback*.  It actually tells you what went wrong.  I'll bet that The second to last line of that traceback began with the word `SyntaxError`, and there probably would something indicating the error was at the end of the `if` statement.  You can use the traceback in the future to debug your errors.

Comment: Also, you are likely getting downvotes because you simply stated the code wasn't working, not specifically *what* wasn't working.  Sometimes, not working means the code failed, and sometimes it means that you didn't get the expected output.

Comment: `"3" != 3`. Make sure you convert user input to the right type before using it.

Comment: You never check the status of `check1`...  Also, you aren't applying your learning about `hm == "3"` to the second round of `if` statements, where you wrote `hm == 3`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks correct, except for the missing colon:

```
if hm == 3 and karma == 8:
    print ("hello whatever")
```

Comment: sorry i missed out on that .. i do have a colon there

Comment: In that case, the conditional is correct and the reason it's not working is because it returns false, i.e. either `hm != 3` or `karma != 8`.

Answer (score 2):

You should check whether the `hm` and `karma` variables actually contain integers. Probably easiest way would be to just add following lines before the `if`:

```
print type(hm)
print type(karma)

if hm == 3 and karma == 8:
    print ("hello whatever")
```

If the output says something like `<type 'str'>`, then you need to convert your strings to integers or just compare with strings: `hm == '3'`.

Answer (score 1):

Is if with problem:

```
if check == "yes" or "Yes" or "yeah":
    print ("good then lets get going")

else:
    print ("bye loser")
    SystemExit
```

charge to:

```
if check.lower() == "yes" or check.lower() == "yeah":
    print ("good then lets get going")
else:
    print ("bye loser")
    sys.exit()
```

sys need

```
import sys
```

Comment: Or better yet, `if check.lower() in ("yes", "yeah"):`

Answer (score -2):

By error, do you mean that "money" and "ticket1" does are not updated? You have

```
if hm == 3 and karma == -5:
   money + 5
   print("you beat the shit out of him and take a golden ticket as well as $5, karma -5, you have", money, "dollars left")
   karma = -10
   ticket1 + 1
```

But I'm guessing that you want to do actually update the values of money and ticket1, so instead of "money + 5" you want to ADD 5 like this: "money += 5". There's no assignment in the former case (just a print, if you do it in console) but there is in the latter case. Same goes for ticket1 and maybe for karma? The code would become this:

```
if hm == 3 and karma == -5:
   money += 5
   print("you beat the shit out of him and take a golden ticket as well as $5, karma -5, you have", money, "dollars left")
   karma = -10
   ticket1 += 1
```